# Get content from bracket

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

With preg_match how can I get the string between the bracket

> Example: sdsdds (sdsd) sdsdsd

And I want the

> sdsd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', 'sdsdds (sdsd) sdsdsd', $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // sdsd
```

Matches characters within parentheses, including blank values. If you want to match multiple instances, you can use preg_match_all.

Comment: hi, if I want to get the second occurrence not the first one, how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $text, $a);
echo $a[1];
```

Comment: Using `.` and `*?` is not very efficient. In this case `[^\)]` is much faster.

Comment: It's barley any faster. I might save 1ms over 1000 `preg_match()` iterations. http://pastebin.com/9XEEHjZ3

Comment: That's true, but you might call it a "best practice" to write as efficient regex (and code in general) as possible. Most regex manuals actually point this out specifically: use `.` as little as possible.

Comment: I'd go for the "low hanging fruit" in terms of performance optimisation and choose readability where there's little in it (like here).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest:

```
#\(([^\)]+)\)#
```

It's not very readable, because all the `(` and `)` must be escaped with `\`.

The `#` are delimiters.

Using `preg_match`:

```
$str = 'sdsdds (sdsd) sdsdsd';
$iMatches = preg_match('#\(([^\)]+)\)#', $str, $aMatches);
echo $aMatches[1]; // 'sdsd'
```